# How can i loop through web pages and run javascript code(or get element data)

Tags: javascript

I want to bruteforce loop though pages for example page1.com - page100.com and get some element data from each. how can i do this? preferably with javascript if possible

Comment: have you heard [`phantomjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt)? its a `nodejs` library that runs browser under the hood, then can send commands such as executing arbitrary javascript on the page context through [`evaluateJavaScript`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate-java-script.html) method.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `node`, take a look at [crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler). it's like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) for `python`.
you could use it like below(from docs):

```
var crawler = require('crawler');

var c = new Crawler({
    rateLimit: 2000,
    maxConnections: 1,
    callback: function(error, res, done) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
            var $ = res.$;
            console.log($('title').text())
        }
        done();
    }
})
c.queue(['http://www.page1.com','http://www.page2.com'], ...)
```